# Adding eventHandler in each label from the code behind for Pager numbers

Tags: asp.net, datalist, pager

My page structure is like this:

```
<div style="BORDER-BOTTOM: black 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: black 1px solid; OVERFLOW-Y: auto; WIDTH: 100%; ; HEIGHT: expression(document.body.clientHeight-270); BORDER-TOP: black 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: black 1px solid"id="divGrid">
<asp:datalist id="dlResults" runat="server" Width="100%" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="0" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
...
</asp:datalist>
</div>

<table class="bodytext8pt" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td><asp:panel id="pnlPager" Runat="server" CssClass="GridFooter"></asp:panel></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the code behind pager is build by the BuildPager function:

```
    private void BuildPager(DataTable dt)
    {
        pnlPager.Controls.Clear();
        Label l = new Label();
        l.Text = " (" + pgResults.PageCount.ToString("#,##0") + " pages, " + dt.Rows.Count.ToString("#,##0") + " records ) ";
        pnlPager.Controls.Add(l);
        for (int i = 0; i < pnlPager.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            if (pnlPager.Controls[i].ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridLinkButton")
            {
                try
                {
                    LinkButton c = (LinkButton) pnlPager.Controls[i];
                    c.CssClass = "GridFooter";
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
            }
        }
        pnlPager.Attributes.Add("class", "GridFooter");
        l = new Label();
        l.Width = Unit.Pixel(5);
        pnlPager.Controls.AddAt(0, l);

        LinkButton lb = null;
        lb = new LinkButton();
        lb.Text = "Previous";
        lb.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "goPage(" + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(pgResults.CurrentPageIndex) - 1) + ");");
        lb.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(pgResults.CurrentPageIndex) - 1);
        if (pgResults.CurrentPageIndex == 0)
        {
            lb.Enabled = false;
            lb.Style.Add("cursor", "default");
        }
        else
        {
            lb.Attributes.Add("class", "GridFooter");
        }
        **lb.Click += new EventHandler(Pager_Click);
        pnlPager.Controls.AddAt(0, lb);**

        l = new Label();
        l.Width = Unit.Pixel(5);
        pnlPager.Controls.AddAt(0, l);

        lb = new LinkButton();
        lb.Text = "First";
        lb.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "goPage(0);");
        lb.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(0);
        if (pgResults.CurrentPageIndex == 0)
        {
            lb.Enabled = false;
            lb.Style.Add("cursor", "default");
        }
        else
        {
            lb.Attributes.Add("class", "GridFooter");
        }
        **lb.Click += new EventHandler(Pager_Click);
        pnlPager.Controls.AddAt(0, lb);**

        l = new Label();
        l.Width = Unit.Pixel(5);
        pnlPager.Controls.AddAt(0, l);

        //Build the numeric links..
        for(int i=0; i< pgResults.PageCount; i++)
        {
            l = new Label();
            l.Width = Unit.Pixel(5);
            pnlPager.Controls.AddAt(pnlPager.Controls.Count - 1, l);

            lb = new LinkButton();
            lb.Text = Convert.ToString(i+1);
            lb.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "goPage(" + Convert.ToString(i) + ");");
            lb.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(i);
            if (pgResults.CurrentPageIndex == i)
            {
                lb.Enabled = false;
                lb.Style.Add("cursor", "default");
            }
            else
            {
                lb.Attributes.Add("class", "GridFooter");
                **lb.Click += new EventHandler(Pager_Click);**
            }

            pnlPager.Controls.AddAt(pnlPager.Controls.Count - 1, lb);
        }

        //End of numeric links
        l = new Label();
        l.Width = Unit.Pixel(5);
        pnlPager.Controls.AddAt(pnlPager.Controls.Count - 1, l);

        lb = new LinkButton();
        lb.Text = "Next";
        lb.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "goPage(" + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(pgResults.CurrentPageIndex) + 1) + ");");
        lb.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(pgResults.CurrentPageIndex) + 1);
        if (pgResults.CurrentPageIndex == pgResults.PageCount - 1)
        {
            lb.Enabled = false;
            lb.Style.Add("cursor", "default");
        }
        else
        {
            lb.Attributes.Add("class", "GridFooter");
        }
        **lb.Click += new EventHandler(Pager_Click);**
        pnlPager.Controls.AddAt(pnlPager.Controls.Count - 1, lb);

        l = new Label();
        l.Width = Unit.Pixel(5);
        pnlPager.Controls.AddAt(pnlPager.Controls.Count - 1, l);

        lb = new LinkButton();
        lb.Text = "Last";
        lb.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "goPage(" + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(pgResults.PageCount) - 1) + ");");
        lb.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(pgResults.PageCount) - 1);
        if (pgResults.CurrentPageIndex == pgResults.PageCount - 1)
        {
            lb.Enabled = false;
            lb.Style.Add("cursor", "default");
        }
        else
        {
            lb.Attributes.Add("class", "GridFooter");
        }
        **lb.Click += new EventHandler(Pager_Click);**
        pnlPager.Controls.AddAt(pnlPager.Controls.Count - 1, lb);

        l = new Label();
        l.Width = Unit.Pixel(5);
        pnlPager.Controls.AddAt(pnlPager.Controls.Count - 1, l);


    }
```

Number labels are added with the clicking events:

```
private void Pager_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton) sender;
            pgResults.CurrentPageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(lb.CommandArgument);
            BindList(false);
        }
```

But when i am clicking these numbers or 'next','previous' this pager_click is not firing.
Have i added eventhandlers in a correct way.
Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: What's in your Page_load function? When do you call BuildPager() ?

Comment: Modified the ques. Please suggest if i have added eventhandlers in BuildPager for each label in a currect ay  or not.. and they are not firing when debuggin.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the reasion.
Dynamically created controls are lost on the page load,
so we need to again load them in postback.